# In Bigquery can I join two tables using Contains/Not Contains with wildcards?

Tags: join, google-bigquery, wildcard, contains

I am trying to join two tables where values from the first table need to be included in values in one field from the second table but excluded from values in a different field. All fields are non-array strings.

As an example, I have table1 that I wanted joined to table2 on the conditions where table1.field1 is in table2.field1yes but not in table2.field1no.

table1 has rows that should join with rows in table2 as follows:

- table1.field1 = '123100'

  - table2.field1yes = '___100,___200'
  - table2.field2no  = Null
- table1.field1 = '321300'

  - table2.field1yes = %
  - table2.field1no  = '___100,___200'

Where _ represents a single character wildcard and % represents 0 or more character wildcard

Written in code, I've tried to do the following to join the tables in the example above:

```
WITH
  table1  AS (SELECT '123100' field1 UNION ALL
              SELECT '321300'),
  table2  AS (SELECT 'data1' data, 'r\'^([\\d]+100|[\\d]+200)$\'' field1yes, '' field1no UNION ALL
              SELECT 'data2',      'r\'^([0-9A-Za-z])$\'',                   'r\'^([\\d]+100|[\\d]+200)$\'')

SELECT
  *
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON 0=0
  AND     REGEXP_CONTAINS(table1.field1, table2.field1yes)
  AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(table1.field1, table2.field1no)
```

But it returns no results, even though the following does returns the first row from table1 a result as expected:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table1
WHERE 0=0
  AND     REGEXP_CONTAINS(table1.field1, r'^([\d]+100|[\d]+200)$')
```

and the following returns the second row from table1:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table1
WHERE 0=0
  AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(table1.field1, r'^([\d]+100|[\d]+200)$')
```

Is this the right approach? If so, what tweaks do I need to make to my query to return results? If not, is there a different solution to match these two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> Is this the right approach?

Yes, you can preset your regexp and then use it in REGEXP functions

> what tweaks do I need to make to my query to return results?

I hope below makes it very clear what was "wrong" in your original query. I mostly mean within TCE for table2 (specifically - field1yes and field1no)

```
#standardSQL
WITH table1  AS (
  SELECT '123100' field1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '321300'
), table2  AS (
  SELECT 'data1' data, r'^([\d]+100|[\d]+200)$' field1yes, '' field1no UNION ALL
  SELECT 'data2',      r'^([0-9A-Za-z])$',                   r'^([\d]+100|[\d]+200)$'
)
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON REGEXP_CONTAINS(table1.field1, table2.field1yes)
OR NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(table1.field1, table2.field1no)
```

Note: I focused on fixing the main issue with your initial query which was a representation of regexp expressions and assumed that the rest (logic of joining, etc.) is up to you to tune

Comment: That seems to have done the trick with my query-- thanks! Much appreciated.